# No implicit arguments of type Encoder[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I've been trying to learn how to use the map function in scala. However, I keep getting the error `No implicit arguments of type Encoder[Row]`. How can I fix this error without having to create a class that defines how the json is modeled?

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("SparkSQL")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.json("src/main/scala/data.json")

val df2 = df.map(r => r)
df2.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom `Encoder` for `Row` with `RowEncoder` if you have its schema and since `r` did not change you can safely use the schema from the source `DataFrame` `df` without needing to know the schema at compile-time.

You can also use the encoder from the source `DataFrame` and it should be safe likewise.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

val df2 = df.map(r => r)(RowEncoder(df.schema))
val df3 = df.map(r => r)(df.encoder)
```